# Combine lxml XSLT pretty_print with strip-space

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml, pretty-print

I'm cleaning up some gross XML, and so I've had pretty_print = True set in the call to etree.tostring() on my lxml output of the XSL transform. However, that left me with a few junk whitespace nodes from the original input, so I added

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

...but that completely collapses all whitespace, ignoring pretty print. Is there an easy way to make strip-space just apply to the input, and still get lxml to apply pretty print?

Comment: Not sure what I did, but it's working now... I must have had another rule interfering with this somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps?  First strip the spaces, then pretty-print?

Just a thought.

Comment: I'm not manually working with the element tree or the XML string, I'm just using lxml's XSLT transform functionality

Comment: Yeah, all I'm saying is do two transforms.  Is this a one-time cleanup, or something you need to make repeatable?  If it's a one-time thing then doing two transforms shouldn't be a problem.